# Absolute positioning doesn't work in React Native - Android

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I couldn't manage to display the View below on android devices. Is this related to react-navigation? This is working on IOS just fine.

```
// App.tsx
export default function App() {
  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const [pageState, setPageState] = React.useState<NavigationState>();

  const handleGetInitialState = () => {
    setPageState(navigationRef.current?.getRootState());
  };

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={handleGetInitialState}
      onStateChange={(state) => setPageState(state)}
    >
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          zIndex: 99999,
        }}
      />
      <RootNavigation />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Comment: try "elevation" for android

Comment: @cuongtd well, that actually worked but no idea why? Also I managed to display but I can't press it.

Comment: zIndex is applied for ios only, and elevation for android. That's it

Comment: @cuongtd how about pressing though?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I still can't press eventhough it's visible.

Comment: What do you expect it happen? where is you code to handle press event?

Comment: I mean I changed it to pressable and added console.log it doesn't work

Comment: have no idea without see you code,  keep in mind View don't have onPress event

Comment: Did you try to place the View below RootNavigation? It might have to do with the ordering.